# How to get results of autocomplete maps only one country?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

How to get results of **autocomplete** maps **only one country**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which API you are using. Using `Google Places API`, according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests) there is an optional `components` parameter. From docs:

> components — A grouping of places to which you would like to restrict
>   your results. Currently, you can use components to filter by country.
>   The country must be passed as a two character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2
>   compatible country code. For example: components=country:fr would
>   restrict your results to places within France.

That means you will just add `&components=country:fr` to your url and autocomplete is restricted to france.

If you use `Google maps Js API`'s `PlacesService` you can restrict the results of google maps places autocomplete using `componentsRestriction` [parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions). There is a `country` attribute, which according to the docu:

> Restricts predictions to the specified country (ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2
>   country code, case insensitive). E.g., us, br, au.

**EDIT**

If you didn't choose API yet, here is a simple example (Notice this line: `country: 'us'` , you will have to input your desired country code there. List of codes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2). Needs to be lower case!):

```js
var pac_input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');


$(function() {
  // Initialize Autocomplete
  var options = {
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'us' //PUT YOUR COUNTRY CODE HERE!!
    }
  };
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pac_input, options);
});
```

```html
Input location here:<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you bro for your answer! I was read already but I've not yet clearly. Could you help me the example please! Thanks for advance!

Comment: You just first need to tell me which API you are using. Can you share the code you already have?

Comment: Oh! I've not yet have Google maps Js API. I think it is the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a simple example. Just edit `country: ...` line to reference country you need

Comment: You make my day Matej P! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: No problem, if you like the answer please accept it.