# Google map Auto Complete filter by country using bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

How to restrict the autocomplete suggestions only for US ( country). Here is my code so far,

```
<div class="search-result">
                    <form action="" method="post" class="clearfix">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter City or Zip Code" class="searchBox" id="search-result" autocomplete="on">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-brown"></button>
                    </form>
                    <div class="marker-list">
                        <ul>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And Javascript code is below. Please note that there is more code and this works without filtering results for US,

```
inputResult = document.getElementById("search-result"), 
    searchBoxResult = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(inputResult), 

searchBoxResult.addListener("places_changed", function () {

        // Clear old markers
        markers.forEach(function(place) {
            place.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        var 
            places = searchBoxResult.getPlaces(), 
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(), 
            searchPlace = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: places[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: places[0].geometry.location.lng()});

        $(".search-result form").submit();

        getPlacesList(searchPlace, customPlaces, searchRadius);

        var placesFilter = function (element) {
            return distance(element.LatLng, searchPlace) < searchRadius;
        };

        var j=0;
        customPlaces.forEach(function (place) {
            if(place.distance<=20){
                createMarker(place,j++);
            }
        });

        customPlacesFiltered = customPlaces.filter(placesFilter);

        customPlacesFiltered.forEach(function(place) {
            bounds.extend(place.LatLng);
        });

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
```

My api request is,

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxx&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap&sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&components=country:us&ext=.js" async defer></script>
```

How to restrict resluts only for US using this method. Please help.

Comment: Please Help. I spent hours for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get results of autocomplete maps only one country?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373930/how-to-get-results-of-autocomplete-maps-only-one-country)

Comment: @geocodezip Actually I don't want to use maps.Autocomplete

Comment: Like using bounds

Comment: Please fix the title of your question.

Comment: You may be interested in the 2 FRs linked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849139/google-autocomplete-to-a-specific-city/39871027#39871027

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SearchBox` offers fewer options than `Autocomplete` for restricting the search. In the former, you can bias the search towards a given LatLngBounds. In the latter, you can restrict the search to a particular country and particular place types, as well as setting the bounds.

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
   new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759), // LatLng of the north-east corner of US
   new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631)  // LatLng of the south-west corner of US
);  

var input = document.getElementById('search-result');

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, { bounds: defaultBounds });
```

in `Autocomplete` we have [componentRestrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-component-restriction)

```
var options = { componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' } };
var input = document.getElementById('search-result');

var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```