# Google autocomplete to a specific city

Tags: php, google-maps, autocomplete, google-geocoding-api

I already create a geocode api on google console. I have a search box input with the google autocomplete in my site and I would like to set a specific city to my geocode api and integrate it in my web app. The city is: toulouse, Country: France.

When the customer type his address on the search box, I want it to only search all address in the city of toulouse, based on the center of toulouse with covered distance of 20 km.

Here is my code based on the file Function.php

```
 public function geoCoding($lat='',$lng='')
{                       
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER["https"]) ? 'https' : 'http';
    if ($protocol=="http"){
        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$lat.",".$lng."&sensor=true";
    } else $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$lat.",".$lng."&sensor=true";

    $google_geo_api_key=getOptionA('google_geo_api_key');
    if (!empty($google_geo_api_key)){
        $url=$url."&key=".urlencode($google_geo_api_key);
    }

    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
    if (!empty($data)){
        $result = json_decode($data,true);                 
        //dump($result);
        if (!isset($result['results'])){
            return false;
        }
        if (is_array($result['results']) && count($result['results'])>=2){
            $location = array();
             foreach ($result['results'][0]['address_components'] as $component) {
               switch ($component['types']) {
                  case in_array('street_number', $component['types']):
                    $location['street_number'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                  case in_array('route', $component['types']):
                    $location['street'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                  case in_array('neighborhood', $component['types']):
                    $location['street2'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;  
                  case in_array('sublocality', $component['types']):
                    $location['sublocality'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                  case in_array('locality', $component['types']):
                    $location['locality'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                  case in_array('administrative_area_level_2', $component['types']):
                    $location['admin_2'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                  case in_array('administrative_area_level_1', $component['types']):
                    $location['admin_1'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                  case in_array('postal_code', $component['types']):
                    $location['postal_code'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                  case in_array('country', $component['types']):
                    $location['country'] = $component['long_name'];
                    $location['country_code'] = $component['short_name'];
                    break;
               }
             }                                   
             return $location;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is a 'radius' parameter..  — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Note that radius must not be included if rankby=distance (described under Optional parameters below) is specified   . Check this link  https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: I don't think this is related to the radius parameter in Places API, the code above uses only the Geocoding API, and it's not clear to me what OP means with "google autocomplete", but the code doesn't show any trace of using the Places Autocomplete API.

Answer (score 1):

Your description sounds like you are using the [Search Box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox) widget in the Maps JavaScript API's Places library, but your code only shows use of [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) in the Geocoding API web service.

Since I think only the former makes sense, I'll venture you'll be interested in the following feature requests that would allow you to restrict autocomplete to a city:

- [Issue 8606](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8606): places bound restrict
- [Issue 4433](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4433): allow componentRestrictions to filter same components as the geocoding API service

For now, the options I know of are:

- Set the Search box `bounds` to those of the city (which you can get from Geocoding API) and rely on the widget to prefer (not restrict) suggestions within those bounds, or
- Build your own widget using [AutocompleteService.getQueryPredictions()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service) and do your own after-the-fact filtering to remove suggestions, but that would be very tricky because the name of the city will not necessarily always be part of the suggestion.